# Sort div by value

Tags: javascript

this is one div, I have many `<div class="is-visible item-box__container">`
I need to sort all `<div class="is-visible item-box__container">`
by value of `js-favourite-count`,
is that possible?

My div:

```
<div class="is-visible item-box__container">
  <section class="item-box js-catalog-item" data-id="377519381" data-distance="7.5 km" data-track-event="user.click_list_item" data-track-event-params="{&quot;id&quot;:377519381,&quot;content_type&quot;:&quot;item&quot;,&quot;channel&quot;:&quot;c&quot;,&quot;content_source&quot;:&quot;catalog&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:2}">

    <figure class="item-box__media media media--item">
  <div class="media__placeholder">


      <figcaption class="media-caption">
          <div class="media-caption__header">
            <a class="item-box__brand" href="/brand/g-shock">G-Shock</a>
          </div>
        <div class="media-caption__body">
          Montre G-SHOCK, choc resist 
En très bon état, très peu portée
Noire et verte
        </div>
      </figcaption>

    <a class="media__image-wrapper js-item-link is-loaded" data-brand="G-Shock" style="background-color: #E0DACA" href="/hommes/montres/377519381-montre-casio-g-shock">
      <img alt="Montre Casio G-SHOCK" title="Montre Casio G-SHOCK" width="310" height="430" class="js-item-thumbnail item-thumbnail lazy-thumbnail __act_as_lazy loaded" data-src="https://images.vinted.net/thumbs/310x430/07155_aGa3Ye8bvFPHqMWKFzjFSLyP.jpeg?1577297436$80bbacb963888041f628527d9953a9f002a27897" data-item-id="377519381" data-item-source="c" data-content-type="item" data-content-source="catalog" data-item-owner-id="31967105" data-disable-tracking="false" data-bumped="false" data-page="1" data-per-page="24" style="background-color: #E0DACA" src="https://images.vinted.net/thumbs/310x430/07155_aGa3Ye8bvFPHqMWKFzjFSLyP.jpeg?1577297436$80bbacb963888041f628527d9953a9f002a27897">

</a>  </div>
</figure>


  <div class="item-box__details">
      <a class="item-box__avatar circle u-float-right is-loaded" href="/membres/31967105-nicolascarpenzano">
        <img width="30" height="30" data-src="https://images.vinted.net/thumbs/50x50/05ac7_CNKk3J2PPa4vaP26wpPApxJQ.jpeg?1575225047$9534574dc11ad39f9b48bc94c13dcbc7333a9229" class="item-box__avatar-picture circle lazy-thumbnail __act_as_lazy loaded" src="https://images.vinted.net/thumbs/50x50/05ac7_CNKk3J2PPa4vaP26wpPApxJQ.jpeg?1575225047$9534574dc11ad39f9b48bc94c13dcbc7333a9229">
</a>
    <div class="item-box__title">
          <span>35,00 €</span>
    </div>

    <div class="item-box__subtitle u-align-items-center">
      <div class="u-flexbox">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="item-box__footer">
  <ul class="nav item-box__nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="u-flexbox u-justify-content-between">
        <div>


          <div class="u-flexbox u-align-items-center js-toggle-favourite-state u-cursor-pointer is-fav-loaded" data-entry-type="10" data-entry-id="377519381" data-state="false" data-entity-title="Montre Casio G-SHOCK" data-currency="€" data-price="35.0" data-count="4" data-label="count" data-source="item" data-ui-components="true">            <div class="js-favourite-icon">
              <div class="js-favourite-on u-line-height-default u-hidden">
                <div class="c-icon--small c-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill="#FB7567" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 5.73685c0 2.9354 2.664 5.029 4.667 6.60768C6.75 13.9842 7.333 14.33613 8 15c.667-.66387 1.224-1.0508 3.333-2.65547C13.366 10.79883 16 8.64027 16 5.70486c0-4.30814-5.333-6.63868-8-2.65547C5.333-.93384 0 1.3967 0 5.73683z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
              </div>

            <div class="js-favourite-off u-line-height-default "></div>
            <div class="c-spacer--small c-spacer--vertical c-spacer"></div>
            <div class="js-favourite-count">4</div></div>

         </div>

          <div>Boosté</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</footer>


</section></div>
```

Comment: Yep, select the containers, call `sort()` on the resulting array, and inside the comparitor callback lookup the nested favourite count for both elements being compared and perform the equality validation

Comment: Was my answer satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to update the page with the divs in sorted order or just sort a variable containing the divs in JavaScript. If you don't need to actually update the page, leave out the second half of the code.

```
//SORT ELEMENTS IN JAVASCRIPT
var sortedItemBoxContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.is-visible.item-box__container');
sortedItemBoxContainers.sort(function(a, b){
    a = (a.getElementsByClassName("js-favourite-count").length > 0 ? Number(a.getElementsByClassName("js-favourite-count")[0].innerHTML) : 0) || 0;//if js-favourite-count exists, grab the value and parse it to a number. Or, if it does not exist, use 0 (i.e. ": 0"). Then, if the parsed value is NaN, use 0 (i.e. "|| 0").
    b = (b.getElementsByClassName("js-favourite-count").length > 0 ? Number(b.getElementsByClassName("js-favourite-count")[0].innerHTML) : 0) || 0;

    if(a < b) return -1;
    if(b < a) return 1;
    return 0;
});

//UPDATE THE USER INTERFACE
var sortedItemBoxContainerHTMLStrings = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sortedItemBoxContainers.length; i++) sortedItemBoxContainerHTMLStrings[i] = sortedItemBoxContainers[i].outerHTML;//store the sorted html strings in order

itemBoxContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.is-visible.item-box__container');//grab the elements again in their natural order
for(var i = itemBoxContainers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){//I always loop through arrays backwards when I'm destroying/removing values as I go along to stop iteration from being affected by the changes
    itemBoxContainers[i].outerHTML = sortedItemBoxContainerHTMLStrings[i];//replace each element's HTML with the corresponding sorted element's HTML
}
```

NOTE: If the `js-favourite-count` element doesn't exist or contains an invalid number value, we use a default value of 0 for sorting purposes. If you plan to use negatives in some `js-favourite-count` elements, you may want to change 0 to -99999999999 or some value that will always be the lowest.